# Am I qualified for Australian Skilled Migration?

Tags: australia, skilled-migration

After high school (10th Standard), I obtained a 3-year diploma in mechanical engineering and have 10 years of work experience. Would I be eligible for permanent residence in Australia?

Comment: It looks like Bachelor's degrees in ME take 4 years in Australia, following 12 years of schooling, so you might not get any points for education. The 10 years, if it's directly related to ME will help. You should look at the [MSA booklet](https://www.engineersaustralia.org.au/sites/default/files/2017-11/MSA%20Booklet%20August%202017%20-%20PTE%20updates.pdf) from Engineers Australia as they'll have to certify your work experience.